# Android YouTube API Always Giving "Connection To Server Lost"

Tags: android, api, youtube, connection

I have two Free applications listed on Google Play store whose package ids are:

- net.superlinux.irctutorials
- net.superlinux.tcltktutorials

Also:

- BOTH are basically the exact same application code.
- Each has a different list of video tutorials .
- The tutorials are saved in YouTube.
- The application code uses Android YouTube API.

Now, the net.superlinux.tcltktutorials working fine; whereas, the net.superlinux.irctutorials keeps telling me "Connection is lost to server" although you'll notice from the Admob ads that there is Internet. I tried changing the YouTube Developer key and still no luck at all.

So... what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Same problem here with some specific videos, did you manage to find out the reason for these errors?